# LUA: Looking for a specific table by its variable

Tags: lua, inventory, items, take

I'm currently starting work on a text adventure game in Lua--no addons, just pure Lua for my first project. In essence, here is my problem; **I'm trying to find out how I can do a "reverse lookup" of a table using one of its variables.** Here's an example of what I've tried to do:

```
print("What are you trying to take?")
bag = {}
gold = {name="Gold",ap=3}
x = io.read("*l")
if x == "Gold" then
     table.insert(bag,gold)
     print("You took the " .. gold.name .. ".")
end
```

Obviously, writing a line like this with every single object in the game would be very... exhausting--especially since I think I'll be able to use this solution for not just taking items but movement from room to room using a reverse lookup with each room's (x,y) coordinates. Anyone have any ideas on how to make a more flexible system that can find a table by the player typing in one of its variables? Thanks in advance!

-blockchainporter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't directly answer your question as you asked it, but I think it would serve the purpose of what you are trying to do.  I create a table called 'loot' which can hold many objects, and the player can place any of these in their 'bag' by typing the name.

```
bag = {}
loot = {
    {name="Gold", qty=3},
    {name="Axe", qty=1},
}

print("What are you trying to take?")
x = io.read("*l")
i = 1
while loot[i] do
    if (x == loot[i].name) then
        table.insert(bag, table.remove(loot,i))
    else
        i = i + 1
    end
end
```

For bonus points, you could check 'bag' to see if the player has some of that item already and then just update the quantity...

```
while loot[i] do
    if (x == loot[i].name) then
        j, found = 1, nil
        while bag[j] do
            if (x == bag[j].name) then
                found = true
                bag[j].qty = bag[j].qty + loot[i].qty
                table.remove(loot,i)
            end
            j = j + 1
        end
        if (not found) then
            table.insert(bag, table.remove(loot,i))
        end
    else
        i = i + 1
    end
end
```

Again, this isn't a 'reverse lookup' solution like you asked for... but I think it is closer to what you are trying to do by letting a user choose to loot something.

My disclaimer is that I don't use IO functions in my own lua usage, so I have to assume that your x = io.read("*l") is correct.

---

PS. If you only ever want objects to have a name and qty, and never any other properties (like condition, enchantment, or whatever) then you could also simplify my solution by using key/val pairs:

```
bag = {}
loot = { ["Gold"] = 3, ["Axe"] = 1 }

print("What are you trying to take?")
x = io.read("*l")
for name, qty in pairs(loot) do
    if x == name then
        bag.name = (bag.name or 0) + qty
        loot.name = nil
    end
end
```

Comment: I would recommend declaring your variables as `local` within functions, loop bodies, etc.

Comment: @Personage Totally agree with local scope; I only left that out to mirror the syntax used in the question

Answer (score 0):

I have a few notes to start before I specifically address your question. (I just want to do this before I forget, so please bear with me!)

I recommend printing to the terminal using `stderr` instead of `stdout`--the Lua function `print` uses the latter. When I am writing a Lua script, I often create a C-style function called `eprintf` to print formatted output to `stderr`. I implement it like this:

```
local function eprintf(fmt, ...)
    io.stderr:write(string.format(fmt, ...))
    return
end
```

Just be aware that, unlike `print`, this function does not automatically append a newline character to the output string; to do so, remember to put `\n` at the end of your `fmt` string.

Next, it may be useful to define a helper function that calls `io.read("*l")` to get an entire line of input. In writing some example code to help answer your question, I called my function `getline`--like the C++ function that has similar behavior--and defined it like this:

```
local function getline()
    local read = tostring(io.read("*l"))
    return read
end
```

If I correctly understand what it is you are trying to do, the player will have an inventory--which you have called `bag`--and he can put items into it by entering item names into `stdin`. So, for instance, if the player found a treasure chest with gold, a sword, and a potion in it and he wanted to take the gold, he would type `Gold` into `stdin` and it would be placed in his inventory.

Based on what you have so far, it looks like you are using Lua tables to create these items: each table has a `name` index and another called `ap`; and, if a player's text input matches an item's name, the player picks that up item.

I would recommend creating an `Item` class, which you could abstract nicely by placing it in its own script and then loading it as needed with `require`. This is a very basic `Item` class module I wrote:

```
----------------
-- Item class --
----------------
local Item = {__name = "Item"}
Item.__metatable = "metatable"
Item.__index = Item

-- __newindex metamethod.
function Item.__newindex(self, k, v)
    local err = string.format(
        "type `Item` does not have member `%s`",
        tostring(k)
    )
    return error(err, 2)
end

-- Item constructor
function Item.new(name_in, ap_in)
    assert((name_in ~= nil) and (ap_in ~= nil))
    local self = {
        name = name_in,
        ap = ap_in
    }
    return setmetatable(self, Item)
end

return Item
```

From there, I wrote a main driver to encapsulate some of the behavior you described in your question. (Yes, I know my Lua code looks more like C.)

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

-------------
-- Modules --
-------------
local Item = assert(require("Item"))

local function eprintf(fmt, ...)
    io.stderr:write(string.format(fmt, ...))
    return
end

local function printf(fmt, ...)
    io.stdout:write(string.format(fmt, ...))
    return
end

local function getline()
    local read = tostring(io.read("*l"))
    return read
end

local function main(argc, argv)
    local gold = Item.new("Gold", 3)
    printf("gold.name = %s\ngold.ap = %i\n", gold.name, gold.ap)
    return 0
end
main(#arg, arg)
```

Now, as for the reverse search which you described, at this point all you should have to do is check the user's input against an `Item`'s name. Here it is in the main function:

```
local function main(argc, argv)
    local gold = Item.new("Gold", 3)
    local bag = {}
    eprintf("What are you trying to take? ")
    local input = getline()
    if (input == gold.name) then
        table.insert(bag, gold)
        eprintf("You took the %s.\n", gold.name)
    else
        eprintf("Unrecognized item `%s`.\n", input)
    end
    return 0
end
```

I hope this helps!